# Find a specific letter in range of strings and toggle the formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, what I want to do is locate a particular letter/character in a specific range and be able to change it to uppercase and lowercase (preferably with a button, i.e. click once, upper; click again, lower)

Currently I have the following:

```
Private Sub btnCapital_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("b").Replace _
What:="d", Replacement:="D", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

This only looks in column B (not the specified range), and this also does not toggle.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the *specified range* ??

Comment: Why there is a ‘jquery’ tag?

Comment: This was an accident sorry!  And the range is B37:B41

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change a little your code:

```
Private Sub btnCapital_Click()
Sheet1.Range("A1:ZZ9000").Columns.Replace _
What:="d", Replacement:="D", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding a simple case to this will also allow me to toggle as I wanted as well.